# I want to display the Flushbar when wrong credentials are entered but instead the execution stops of the following section

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
   try{
      showAlertDialog(context);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass)
      .then((result){
      User user = result.user;
      if(user == null )
       {
          // showAlertDialogs(context);
           setState(() {
           Flushbar(
                  borderRadius: 8.0,
                  title: "Invalid Password/Email",
                          message:
                              "Please enter correct Email and Password",
                          flushbarPosition: FlushbarPosition.BOTTOM,
                          flushbarStyle: FlushbarStyle.FLOATING,
                          reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.decelerate,
                          forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          mainButton: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "OK",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              )),
                          boxShadows: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.blue[800],
                                offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
                                blurRadius: 8.0)
                          ],
                          margin:
                          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
                          isDismissible: true,
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.error_outline,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )..show(context);
                              });
                        }
                           else {
                              showAlertDialog(context);
                              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, _homeRoute(), (_) => false);
                              //  showAlertDialogs(context);

                               }
                             }
                            );
                           }
                           catch(e)
                           {
                             print(e);
                           }
         }
```

this in the stack trace when wrong credentials are given as input

```
/BiChannelGoogleApi( 3302): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@f17202f
E/flutter ( 3302): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception:     [firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
E/flutter ( 3302): #0      catchPlatformException 
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/…/utils/exception.dart:20
E/flutter ( 3302): #1      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter ( 3302): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 3302): #3      _FutureListener.handleError  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:160:20)
E/flutter ( 3302): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError   (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
E/flutter ( 3302): #5      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
E/flutter ( 3302): #6      Future._completeError  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
E/flutter ( 3302): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError  (dart:async-  patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
```

once the `_loginFormKey` is validated ; the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` is called and user is signed in if credentials are correct, but if they are wrong an alert bar (`Flushbar`) should be shown on the bottom of the screen. but somehow this section of the code is ignored by flutter.

*Please note i want to show the `Flushbar` context when wrong credentials are given as input

also question: Does `FirebaseAuth` return a `user` when wrong password is given as an input? or the `user` is `null`?

*Note: i am new to `Firebase` please forgive if i do something wrong!!!!

Comment: You should never put methods like that in setState() also in this case there's no need. Try printing something inside the If statement.

Comment: well i tried printing inside the if statement, when correct credentials are passed print statement is executed but if wrong credentials are passed it still does not print

Comment: remove set state